# XML parse error on ë (crash with accented letters)

Tags: android, xml, sax

I have a crash in an xml file. it occurs on a ë, in this case belgië (dutch for belgium).

I'm busy with searching for an answer but I just can't find a solution.

I'm using the sax parser under Android.
error: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 2, column 204: not well-formed
xml source: http://biohorma.weatheronyoursite.com/villadm_hooikoortsverwachting_be.xml

Side note, i get the data via a stream, is the only option to put this stream to a temp value, replace the illegal character with a valid one and make a new stream of it or can you add something in the stream to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you should use the [String (byte[] bytes, String enc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor, assuming what server sends you is encoded in UTF-8:

```
String properXml = new String(byteArrayIReceivedFromServer, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with the parser - it's acting correctly - but with whatever code is sending the XML.  **ë** needs to be encoded and passed as `&#235;`.  The same also must be done to other accented characters, ampersands and angle brackets.

Comment: Again, depends on the character encoding. Ivan's answer looks right.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace special characters in the xml I think..

See a comprehensive list of chars here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

it says your umlaut e is like : `Ë  &#203;  &Euml;  capital e, umlaut mark`

Then also for [a brief explanation](http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=saxparser3.sql&id=18232) if u feel like reading.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Depends on the character encoding the server sends the data in. UTF-8, for example, handles ë.

Answer (score 0):

The server sends these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 124512
```

Since no charset is specified for content type, the normally correct assumption is US_ASCII. However, the XML payload seems to be encoded in ISO-8859-1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

and the 'ë' is encoded as 0xEB (235). It is very common for servers to encode text payload in ISO-8859-1, so this is something that one simply has to deal with.

My guess is that if you serve the parser with a byte stream directly, it will detect the encoding an act accordingly. If you use a character stream (not recommended), make sure to specify correct encoding.